# adding colored vertical band to excel chart programatically using vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am trying to add colored vertical band to a chart in excel programatically using vba macro.

I have a chart that contains some numbers x-axis from 1 - 50 and I want to add a colored vertical band from 1 - 10 and another one from 10 - 20 with different color and so on.

Any help or clue

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses an image for the plot area background.

This line of code sets the background image. Be sure to update the sheet reference, chart name, and file name as necessary.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.UserPicture "C:\background.png"
```

I use MS Paint to create the various background images required. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new file and set the attributes to be 1 pixel high and X
   pixels wide where X is the number of bands you need.
2. Set the zoom to as large as possible.
3. Using the Pencil tool, color each pixel as you would like the bands
   to appear.
4. Resize the image by 500% horizontal and vertical; do this 2-3 times
   to get an image big enough so it doesn't have to stretch in the
   chart. (Note: leaving it small produces blending of the colored bars
   which can be desirable.)
5. Save the file.

If your charts will have a variable number of points plotted, prepare several background images and then select the appropriate one in your code.

[image]

Comment: You could also do it by adding a number of series (which you could do programatically). Here is a link (http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/) to creating a horizontal bands which you could modify easily enough to create veritcal bands instead.

Comment: the problem that I am reading the horizontal data from another file. so the colored vertical band should be dynamic and even the arrangement of the color on the band could be different i.e. in a graph the red color could be before the blue band and vice verse

Comment: Jon Peltier has an example of vertical bands here: [http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ColoredVerticalBand.html](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ColoredVerticalBand.html). However, his example displays the data in floating bar format and best I can tell there is no way to substitute a line or scatter chart format. If that format is acceptable, his solution can be translated to VBA.

Comment: but Jon Peltier did not explain how to do it programaticaly

Comment: If the format of floating bars works for your data, then you can follow his steps while recording a macro.

Comment: My tutorial [Highlight Certain Time Periods in a Chart](http://peltiertech.com/highlight-certain-time-periods-in-a-chart/) shows how to apply vertical bands to highlight time periods (weekends in this case) in a line chart. Programmatically you need to set up the data, and this data to the chart, change the chart type of the added data to clustered column with gap width of zero.